# Tensorflow 1.6 get the prediction output from estimator.predict()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have this code which just Mnist tesorflow example and I would to do get the prediction for test data

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

# Imports
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)


# Our application logic will be added here
def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
"""Model function for CNN."""
# Input Layer
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

# Convolutional Layer #1
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

# Pooling Layer #1
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

# Convolutional Layer #2 and Pooling Layer #2
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=pool1,
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

# Dense Layer
pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

# Logits Layer
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=10)

predictions = {
    # Generate predictions (for PREDICT and EVAL mode)
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    # Add `softmax_tensor` to the graph. It is used for PREDICT and by the
    # `logging_hook`.
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
}

if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)

# Calculate Loss (for both TRAIN and EVAL modes)
loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

# Configure the Training Op (for TRAIN mode)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, 
train_op=train_op)

# Add evaluation metrics (for EVAL mode)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
    eval_metric_ops = {
        "accuracy": tf.metrics.accuracy(
            labels=labels, predictions=predictions["classes"])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
predicted_classes = tf.argmax(logits, 1)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    predictions = {
        'class_ids': predicted_classes[:, tf.newaxis],
        'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits),
        'logits': logits,
    }
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)


def main(unused_argv):
# Load training and eval data
mnist = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
train_data = mnist.train.images[:54000]  # Returns np.array
train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)[:54000]
eval_data = train_data[:500]  # Returns np.array
eval_labels = train_labels[:500]  # np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, 
dtype=np.int32)
test_data = train_data[1000:]
test_label = train_labels[1000:]
# eval_data = mnist.test.images  # Returns np.array
# eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)

# Create the Estimator
mnist_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="./tmp/mnist_convnet_model")
# Set up logging for predictions
tensors_train_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
# tensors_eval_to_log = {"accuracy": "classes"}
logging_train_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
    tensors=tensors_train_to_log, every_n_iter=6000)
# logging_eval_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
#     tensors=tensors_eval_to_log, every_n_iter=1000)
# Train the model
print("Training Data length:", np.shape(train_data))
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": train_data},
    y=train_labels,
    batch_size=10,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True)

eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": eval_data},
    y=eval_labels,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True)
#     input_fn=train_input_fn,
#     steps=20000,
#     hooks=[logging_hook])
# Evaluate the model and print results

# eval_results = mnist_classifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
# print(eval_results)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=6500)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator=mnist_classifier, 
train_spec=train_spec,eval_spec=eval_spec)

test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": test_data[0]},
    y=test_label,
    num_epochs=1,
    shuffle=True)
# mnist_classifier.train(
test_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=test_input_fn)
predictions = mnist_classifier.predict(test_spec)

print(predictions["logits"][0])
# print(predictions["logits"])

#I got an error when I tried to print this
if __name__ == "__main__":
tf.app.run()
```

the code work will like I got trained model but still when I tried to print the prediction I could find a way to do that. So, any one did this example and print the pridected data not just the evaluation accuracy.

Comment: I have the same question. Does anyone know how to print the prediction?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
training_predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_training_input_fn)
training_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in training_predictions])
validation_predictions = linear_regressor.predict(input_fn=predict_validation_input_fn)
validation_predictions = np.array([item['predictions'][0] for item in validation_predictions])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a generator object and, to print it, you should use

`print(list(predictions)[0])`

Comment: This seems to print only the first prediction. Moreover, `for i in range(300): print(list(predictions)[0])` does not work. Any advice on how to get the following predictions?

Answer (score 0):

Following should print all the predictions -

```
   for i in range(300):

        print(list(predictions)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 outputs = [list(next(predictions).values())[0] for i in range(300)]
```